# Poisson Summation Formulas for Cut and Project Quasicrystals

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, tiling

In Lagarias' paper "Mathematical Quasicrystals and the Problem of Diffraction" http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~lagarias/doc/diffraction.pdf he discusses various ways one might get Poisson summation formulas for certain nonuniform point sets in the plane. More precisely, given a Delone set $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ obtained using a cut and project scheme, consider the tempered distribution
$$\mu_\Lambda = \sum_{x \in \Lambda} \delta_x.$$
We would like to compute $\hat{\mu}_\Lambda$. In section 3 (specifically Thm 3.9 and the surrounding discussion) he seems to indicate that for cut and project sets, we know something about $\hat{\mu}_\Lambda$, but I can't tell how to interpret Thm 3.9 in that context.

Question 1: How close does Thm 3.9 get us to computing $\hat{\mu}_\Lambda$?

Question 2: Do we at least know that $\hat{\mu}_\Lambda$ is a tempered distribution of the form $$\sum_{x \in \Lambda'} c_x\delta_x$$
for some Delone set $\Lambda'$? If so, how much do we know about the set $\Lambda'$?

Edit: In Meyer's paper "Quasicrystals, diophantine approximation and algebraic numbers" he computes a variety of weighted Poisson summation formulas, but falls short of a computation of $\hat{\mu}_\Lambda$. These computations appear to have been done in the 70's. Has anyone tried to improve his results since then?

Comment: Theorem 3.9 merely tells you how to detect a single point mass in the Fourier transform. It says nothing about the absence of a continuous component.

Comment: It detects a point mass in the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation measure of $\mu_\Lambda,$ which we know from other sources has no continuous component for cut and project sets. But does it detect a point mass in $\hat{\mu}_\Lambda?$ He never explicitly states it that way.

Comment: Same story: just average the exponent directly over large balls with respect to $\mu_{\Lambda}$ and observe resonances in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1** let $\gamma$ be the auto-correlation of $\Lambda$. 
It can be proven that
$$ \lim_n \frac{\int_{x+A_n} \bar{\chi(t)} d \mu_\Lambda (t)}{vol(A_n)}(*)$$
exists uniformly in $x$. In the case of Fourier Transformable measures, this limit is exactly $\widehat{\mu_\Lambda}(\{ \chi \})$.

It follows then from a result of Hof that

$$ \widehat{\gamma}(\{ \chi \}) = \left| \lim_n \frac{\int_{A_n} \bar{\chi(t)} d \mu_\Lambda (t)}{vol(A_n)} \right|^2 \,.$$

I think the existence of the limit (*) is covered in a paper by Robert Moody (1).

Also the problem of when the two limits can be connected without the uniformity in $x$ (aka the Bombieri Taylor conjecture) is covered pretty well in a paper by Daniel Lenz (2) [available here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0608026)

**Question 2** The answer is no in general. More precisely, the answer is yes if and only if $\Lambda=L+F$ where $L$ is lattice and $F$ is finite.

There is an old paper by Cordoba (3) which shows that this is not the case, and Lagarias mentions this paper. The proof is pretty technical, and I heard that there might be some issues with the proof though.

In this case, since $\Lambda$ is a Meyer set, there exists a much simpler proof of this claim, which can be found in my paper (Proposition 7.3 in (4))[archiv link](http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.3019)

A much stronger version of this claim was proven recently by Favorov (5) and independently by Kellendonk and Lenz (6) They basically proved that if $\Lambda$ is a Delone set with FLC, and $\delta_\Lambda$ is Fourier Transformable, with a discrete FT, then  $\Lambda=L+F$ where $L$ is lattice and $F$ is finite.

I am actually pretty sure that in general, $\widehat{\mu_\Lambda}$ cannot even be a measure, you have to always treat it as a tempered distribution.

**Bibliography**

1. R. V. Moody,  *Uniform distribution in model sets,*  Canad. Math. Bull. Vol. 45 (1), 123-130, 2002.
2. D. Lenz, *Continuity of eigenfunctions of uniquely ergodic dynamical systems and intensity of Bragg peaks*, Commun. Math. Phys. 287 , 225-258, 2009.
3. A. Cordoba,  *Dirac combs,* Lett. Math. Phys., 17, 191-196, 1989.
4. N.Strungaru,  *On the Bragg Diffraction Spectra of a Meyer Set,* Canadian Journal of Mathematics 65, no. 3, 675-701, 2013.
5. Favorov  *Bohr and Besicovitch almost periodic discrete sets and quasicrystals*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 140, 1761-1767, 2012.
6. J. Kellendonk, D. Lenz,  *Equicontinuous delone dynamical systems* , Canadian Journal of Mathematics 65, 149--170, 2013.

Comment: What are the $A_n$ in the limit?

Comment: $A_n$ is an arbitrary van Hove sequence. Lagarias paper is in $\mathbb R^d$, so you can use $A_n=[-n,n]^d$. Hof's result is proven in $\mathbb R^d$ with the same choice of $A_n$, but if I remember right, Lenz showed in the above mentioned paper (2), that the result is true if $G$ is an arbitrary $\sigma$-compact locally compact abelian group, and $A_n$ is any van Hove sequence....

Comment: I imagine a similar argument can be used to show that patches in the tiling space occur with uniform frequencies (and to compute those frequencies). Would you happen to know of a reference with those sorts of computations? I've seen things like this in a paper of Solomyak, but it was for self-affine tilings rather than cut and projects.

Comment: For cut and project sets it can easily be shown that the frequencies of the points are uniform, there is no need to work with tilings (and I think most of the times one gets more info from the c&p than from tilings). I am pretty sure that the paper by Moody contains the computation,  also, Moody "Model sets a survey" probably also contains something in this direction.